# Changing gridplot using RadioButtonGroup, Python Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Dears,

I have got three gridplot and was trying to replace the gridplots base on Radio Button selection. for example, if I select 611 then grid1 should be visible and when I select 612 (grid2) should be visible. I have been searching but couldn't get to a solution.  I have tried multiple things but nothing works. please help me guide to how to accomplish that.

kindly find below my code.

```
grid1 = gridplot([[V1_Traffic, D1_Traffic]])
grid2 = gridplot([[V2_Traffic, D2_Traffic]])
grid3 = gridplot([[V3_Traffic, D3_Traffic]])

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):

    if button_group.labels[0] == '611':
        curdoc().clear()
        curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
        # curdoc().add_root(grid)
        #lay_out = layout([[button_group]])
        show(grid1)

    if button_group.labels[1] == '612':
        curdoc().clear()
        curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
        # curdoc().add_root(grid2)
        #lay_out = layout([[button_group]])
        show(grid3)

    if button_group.labels[2] == '613':
        curdoc().clear()
        curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
        # curdoc().add_root(grid3)
        #lay_out = layout([[button_group]])
        show(grid3)


button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["611", "612", "613"], active=0)
button_group.on_change("active", update_plot)


# create layout and add to curdoc
lay_out = layout([[button_group]])
curdoc().add_root(grid)
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

Thanks for your time. Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

dears,

I have got the solution and got it to work. kindly find below my code.

```
def update_plot(attrname, old, new):

    if options[button_group.active] == '611':
        curdoc().clear()
        curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
        curdoc().add_root(grid)

    if options[button_group.active] == '612':
        curdoc().clear()
        curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
        curdoc().add_root(p2)

    if options[button_group.active] == '613':
        curdoc().clear()
        curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
        curdoc().add_root(p3)


options = ["611", "612", "613"]
button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=options, active=0)
button_group.on_change("active", update_plot)


# create layout and add to curdoc
lay_out = layout([[button_group]])
curdoc().add_root(grid)
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

Radio buttons are indexed `button_group.labels[0]` was not working, therefore, modifying it by doing an extra step

```
options = ["611", "612", "613"]
button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=options, active=0)
```

and by calling it by

```
if options[button_group.active] == '612'
```

`curdoc().clear()` to clear everything is there on the page and replace it with new grid data.

`curdoc().add_root(lay_out)` to display radio buttons

`curdoc().add_root(p3)` to display the new grid

I am new to programming. I am not sure if it is a good solution or a bad solution but at the moment it works for me:).

thanks again for your time.
Best Regards